# Functional completeness explained

Tags: logic

It is hard for me to grasp the meaning of 'functional completeness'.

Isn't the set of connectives {conjunction, disjunction and negation} the only set which is functional complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A functionally complete set of logical connectives is one which can be used to express all possible truth tables by combining members of the set into a Boolean expression.
{conjunction, disjunction, negation} isn`t the only functionally complete set.
{conjunction, negation} itself can form a functionally complete set.
You know {and,or,not} ( {conjunction,disjunction,negation} ) is functionally complete. Now any instance of disjunction can be replaced with

```
p V q <=> ¬(¬p∧¬q)
```

This means conjunction and disjunction alone can express all possible truth tables.

Comment: So is {conjuction, disjunction} the smallest functional complete set possible?

Comment: If you can consider NAND and NOR as independent, the singleton set {NAND} and {NOR} are themselves functionally independent, but yes NAND is basically NOT (AND) only..